# Updating a list of StaticArrays

Tags: julia

Suppose I have this function, implemented without `StaticArrays`

```
function example_svector_bad(G) 
    vector_list = [ randn(G) for q in 1:1000]
    for i in size(vector_list)
        for g in 1:G
            vector_list[i][g] = vector_list[i][g] * g
        end
    end

    return vector_list
end
```

I'm hoping to implement it using `StaticArrays` for speed gains. However, I don't know how to do it without losing the flexibility of specifying `G`. For example, I could do

```
function example_svector()
    vector_list = [@SVector randn(3) for q in 1:1000]
    for i in size(vector_list)
        vector_list[i] = SVector(vector_list[i][1] * 1, vector_list[i][1] * 2,
        vector_list[i][1] * 3)
    end

    return vector_list
end
```

if I knew that `G = 3` and I had to write out `SVector(vector_list[i][1] * 1, vector_list[i][1] * 2, vector_list[i][1] * 3)`.

Is there a way to implement this for any arbitrary number of `G`?

Comment: If `G=4`, Then you should write `SVector(vector_list[i][1] * 1, vector_list[i][1] * 2, vector_list[i][1] * 3, vector_list[i][1] * 4)` ?

Comment: I could do that, but I lose the flexibility of inputting `G`.

Comment: Explain more. I don't see any `G` in the second script.

Comment: In the second function, I knew `G = 3` a priori. Suppose I wanted to write a function such that the user can specify any `G`. What should I do? The first function doesn't use `StaticArrays`.

Comment: Okay, I will try to help. But keep in mind to provide a minimal example, not a large one! Here you used `1:1000` which is quit big but maybe it would be better to decrease it to `1:5`. This will help us to investigate trough it easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The size of a static vector or array must be known at the compile time.
At the compile time only types are known (rather than values).

Hence your function could look like this:

```
function myRandVec(::Val{G}) where G
    SVector{G}(rand(G))
end
```

Note that `G` is passed as type rather than as value and hence can be used to create a static vector.

This function could be used as:

```
julia> myRandVec(Val{2}())
2-element SVector{2, Float64} with indices SOneTo(2):
 0.7618992223709563
 0.5979657793050613
```

Comment: `SVector{G}(rand(G))` will create an intermediate and unnecessary `Vector`. Better to do `rand(SVector{G})` or `@SVector rand(G)`.

Comment: @DNF - yes you are right. Just everyone remember `G` needs to be passed as `Val{G}`, otherwise `@code_warntype` would show that the code is not type stable.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, there is a mistake in how you are indexing `vector_list`, where you do

```
for i in size(vector_list)
```

Let's see what that does:

```
julia> x = 1:10;

julia> size(x)
(10,)
```

The `size` of `x` is its length in each dimension, for a vector that is just `(10,)` since it has only one dimension. Let's try iterating:

```
julia> for i in size(x)
           println(i)
       end
10
```

It just prints out the number 10.

You probably meant

```
for i in 1:length(vector_list)
```

but it's better to write

```
for i in eachindex(vector_list)
```

since it is more general and safer.

As for your *actual* question, you can use `StaticArrays.SOneTo` which provides a static version of `[1,2,3]`:

```
function example_svector()
    vector_list = [@SVector randn(3) for q in 1:1000]
    N = length(eltype(vector_list))
    c = SOneTo(N)
    for i in eachindex(vector_list)
        vector_list[i] = vector_list[i] .* c
    end
    return vector_list
end
```